# Proving Equality?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this matrix below in the imaga:

[image]

And if you multiply Matrix 2 times with Matrix A you get below:

[image]

But after that how does this equal each others image below:

[image]

The determinant of 2A becomes 1/4 when i calculate it but i don't
understand this equality?
I wonder how 1/4 * [[3,1],[5,2]] can just so instantly become equal to
1/2*[[2,-1],[-5,3]]??

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There is a formula for the inverse of a 2 by 2 matrix. Apply it to $2A$ and to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}adj(A)$$

where $adj(A)$ is the adjoint of $A$ which is the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

Now, from step 2 to step 3 (in the image given), we have taken the $\frac12$ inside the matrix (and thus multiplied each element by $\frac12$). Now, the nice observation at this point is the fact that the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1  \\ -5 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ at this step is exactly equal to $A^{-1}$.

Useful Trick to remember:

If,
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a &b  \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$ then, $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}\begin{pmatrix} d &-b  \\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$$

ie. you exchange the elements on the main diagonal and flip the signs of the elements on the off diagonal.

Comment: For your "Useful Trick" to work, need determinant of $A$ to be $1.$ [You didn't mention that when the trick cited but maybe it was implied. Still good to re-state requirement.]

Answer (score 2):

Since the determinant is multilinear for any $n \times n$ matrix $\vert kA \vert = k^n\vert A\vert$. Since $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\vert A \vert} adj(A)$ then $(kA)^{-1} = \frac{1}{k^n} A^{-1} adj(kA)$. Also note that $\frac{1}{4}A= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}A)$.